# Unable to Register Microsoft.DataFactory using Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-powershell

I am new to `Azure Data Factory` and `PowerShell` and trying to register `Microsoft.DataFactory` in Azure subscription using following command in `Azure PowerShell`

```
Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.DataFactory
```

but getting this error.

[image]

Could anyone help please

Comment: Have you logged into azure? New azure module command for that is --> Login-AzAccount . I think the old command was --> Login-AzureRmAccount . I'm looking into it further, just try that if you haven't already.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay. managed to logged in but same issue

Comment: you may want to close out your PowerShell console and reopen it. Then log back in, make sure you are on the right subscription (if you have multiple), and try the command again. I can't seem to reproduce your error.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay. Thank you for help, i registered via portal against same subscription, closed and reopened and executed the same command just to test what will happen if its registered via poral, now see registrationstate : registered in the console

Comment: I moved my comments to the answer. Let me know if I should add any other steps that you did, for the sake of having the full answer for someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close out your PowerShell console and reopen it. Then log back in, make sure you are on the right subscription (if you have multiple), and try the command again.

**Log Into Azure:**

> New azure module command for that is -->
>   Login-AzAccount . I think the old command was --> Login-AzureRmAccount
>   .